# Best Alternative OF WinForm On Linux

Tags: software-recommendation

I am a computer science student

In our syllabus, we have a new subject called "Introduction to VB.net" on this subject we have to learn to make desktop applications Using WinForm's Drag And Drop Designer With Vb language

I am using Linux so I want the best alternative for WinForm that can Run with Vb and have a designer too...

Comment: No, because Mono develop with winform and its designer is very old and not stable..i think its discontinued to develop winform for Linux

Comment: There is no viable alternative. VB.Net is very much a Windows-specific tool. If you need this for school, you can get [a legit Windows VM from Microsoft](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) in the form of a browser compatibility image, install VisualStudio, and use that for 90 days 